# Ejected Expo app throwing error during deployment to iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, expo

I am building an ejected Expo app. After some recent SDK updates, which included an update to Xcode 10.1, I am running into a difficult Xcode error when I run the app. This error occurs after the build (which completes successfully) but before any javascript is packaged and deployed to the app from the Metro Bundler. I haven't made any custom code changes since when this was last working, nor have I written any native code yet, so this is all expokit code.

I have already tried to change SDKs (this happens with Expokit 31 and 32), as well as change versions of Xcode (both 10.1 and 10.2-beta).

Here's the output of the backtrace from Xcode:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x000000011741523e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000117456c1c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 285
    frame #2: 0x00000001170df01d libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x0000000116e6c9d1 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 231
    frame #4: 0x0000000116e6cb6f libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 267
    frame #5: 0x000000011467be6d libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 97
    frame #6: 0x0000000116e78a2e libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x0000000116e78aa3 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 51
    frame #8: 0x000000011467bdf2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_terminate + 9
    frame #9: 0x0000000116f83dc9 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 28
    frame #10: 0x0000000116f91080 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1540
    frame #11: 0x0000000115e798f9 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #12: 0x0000000115e73fa6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2310
    frame #13: 0x0000000115e73352 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    frame #14: 0x00000001188022fe GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 65
    frame #15: 0x000000011f5e12c2 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 140
  * frame #16: 0x000000010ad3cd40 ping`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffee4ec3248) at main.m:8:16
    frame #17: 0x0000000116ff8861 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #18: 0x0000000116ff8861 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Ideally this runs and displays the app in the iOS simulator without an issue. Any advice on additional troubleshooting recommendations (I'm new to Xcode) or advice on how to proceed from here would be much appreciated.

**Update**: 
After downgrading multiple versions, this problem goes away on SDK 26. It starts happening after an upgrade to Expo SDK 27. Here are the diagnostics:

System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.3
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 9.4.1/9F2000 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the SDK version wasn't the issue. I had two versions of Xcode on my machine (9.4.1 and 10.1) which caused the issue. After deleting 10.1, this built and ran as expected.